Declaring Global variable inside of a function in C++
I have a function inside a class. I want to declare about 10 global variables of different types: vector, queue, int, 2d-vector etc., How do I do this?
Also I just cant declare the variables outside of the function, I want the variables to be declared inside the function.

Too much undefined here. Why can't the variables be declared outside the function? How can something declared inside a function be global? Put another way, what does global variable mean to you? Finally, perhaps most importantly, what problem as you actually really trying to solve? Say what that is, and someone might tell you what the right way to do it is. Wishing that C++ has facillities that it doesn't won't solve anything.

Global variables as defined by C++ have a number of featues, they have scope, they have lifetime, they have a (partially) specified time of initialisation. Which of these features are important to you in the variables you are trying to declare?

@john It is because vectors are there and i dont exactly know the length of the vector beforehand

Then I would say declare the vectors as normal global variables and then resize them when you know what size they should be. vec.resize(whatever)

No you don't want to define globale variables, they should be avoided by design! For any shared state... learn about dependency injection.

Global variables can't be defined inside a function in C++. They can technically be declared inside a function in a non-definition, but I highly doubt that this is what you want. It is a feature that exists for historical reasons and is not really used in practice.
C++ has lexical scoping, so constructs like global in Python, which has dynamic scoping, that allows introducing a global variable inside a function, can't work in C++.
Whatever you are trying to do is probably not dependent on being able to do this though. Unfortunately you didn't provide sufficient context to give a solution.
Also, as a general guideline, always try to avoid global variables in C++, except when they are constants that can be marked constexpr.
